# accessing custom managers via a _set option in django

Tags: django, django-models

I am having two models and a custom Manager:

```
class ActiveModelAManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        return super(ActiveModelAManager,self).get_query_set().filter( active = True)

class ModelA(models.Model):
    name = CharField(....)
    active = BooleanField()

    active_models = ActiveModelAManager()
    objects = models.Manager()

class ModelB(models.Model):
    modelA = ForeignKey(ModelA)
```

in my view I am passing ModelA to the template and I would like to access ModelB_set but using my active_models manager instead of objects ?

so if I am doing this :

```
{{ ModelB.modelb_set.all }}
```

I am accessing the objects manager but I want to access the active_models.
Same problem goes when I am trying to access the custom manager via my view.

Any idea how can I accomplish this ?

Comment: For the sake of all active StackOverflow users, if you get a solution that works, please mark the answer as accepted, so that people don't spend time answering if answer is not needed anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure whether I got your question right, but in order to query for the modelB objects which reference to an active ModelA object, in your view you can just write.

```
active_modelA_objects = ModelA.active_models.all().values_list('pk', flat=True)
modelB_objects_with_active_modelA = ModelB.objects.filter(modelA__in=active_modelA_objects)
```

Related docs:

[values-list](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values-list)

[__in](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#in)